# layout is bigger than my screen but it's fine on the emulator

Tags: android

I'm designing a main page menu for an android app ... my problem is that the design look like in the design editor in the emulator but looks bigger than my screen real  device ... well it's telling me to add some details so I will add some useless lines so I can post my question

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lJal.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VP1r.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_consulter_contrat" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Contrat"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Consulter votre contrat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_suivre_sinistre" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Sinistre"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Suivre un sinistre"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_localiser" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Agences"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="STAR la plus proche"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_demander_devis" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Devis"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Demander un devis"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ` well it's telling me to add some details so I will add some useless lines`. That is not meant to add useless lines. Add the details of the question, like screenshot from the real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this I think this will work on every screen. 
Since your **size is fix** so in small phone your UI will be cut but i use the phone width which make **UI** **more flexible** to use in approximately in every screen :)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fcfcfc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_consulter_contrat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Contrat"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Consulter votre contrat"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_suivre_sinistre" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Sinistre"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Suivre un sinistre"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_localiser" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Agences"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="STAR la plus proche"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_demander_devis" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Devis"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Demander un devis"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... it worked bro but what did you change exactly ?

Comment: since you are using fixed size in small screen it will not work if your size is way too big. But i use weight which get the exact width of the screen and i divide it into 2 so that your horizontally your 2 cards can fit easily @dridinho

Comment: see how i use card android:layout_weight="1" and make its width 0dp so that it will make him flexible according to screen

Comment: I really though that I got it but it seems that I'm not ... can you please check my post under this section ?

Comment: sorry can you clarify. i didn't understand,

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using ConstraintLayout instead to make your layouts responsive 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout